# format for search query, asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a search portal for school. And I am having one advance search form in which users can select courses, school state city etc.

I am having this below query after search button click:

```
select * from tbl_xxx 
where state = 'xxx' and city = 'xxx' and area = 'xxx' 
      and ( course LIKE 'x' or course LIKE 'Std 10') 
      and gender ='xxx'
```

Actually my problem is in course selection. Value in table for course fields will be like any of the below options:

```
std 1, std 2 ,std3, std 4
std 10, std 11&12 commerce
std 10, std 11&12 science
std 1, std 2 ,std3, std 4, std 5, std 6, std 7, std 8, std 9, std 10, std 11&12 commerce
std 1, std 2 ,std3, std 4, std 5, std 6, std 7, std 8, std 9, std 10, std 11&12 science
```

If I remove all the data from course field and add 'std 10' only, than only results are displayed.
If I am searching with like operator with eg query given above, I should be getting last four fields because it contains 'std 10', but I am not getting any results.

I know there is some problem in search query only. But I don't know any operator rather than `LIKE` to use for a problem like this.

My application is in asp.net (C#).

Comment: can you format the table it's not readable (to me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at using stored procs for your queries, and then use maybe [`ADO.NET to query the DB`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310070)...

Also, a `like` statement needs a **wild-card**, e.g.

`select....where course like 'Std 1%'` <- this would get all courses that have the first 5 chars as Std 1.

Comment: thank you so much it worked, just 1 little change, i have to put % on both the side instead of 1.

Comment: only use the wildcard where needed, e.g. if all your courses start with Std, then only use the wildcard on the right side i.e. 'Std%' as this is better for performance.